# Power BI DAX measure returns syntax error during parsing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created the following measure for my MTTR_M table.

```
afiber_iptv = 
VAR _afiber_iptv = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(MTTR_M[mttr]), MTTR_M [product] = "fiber/iptv") 
RETURN 
IF(ISBLANK(_afiber_iptv), “No Data”, CONVERT(_afiber_iptv,STRING))
```

However, I'm getting the following output error when I run it.

"The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 4, Offset 27, “.

On line 4 "No Data" is the only thing with red lines underneath and grayed out. When looking at the Data Transformation screen, there are no errors I can see in the data. Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: Your double quotes are wrong.  You've apparently pated from a source that changes `"` to `“`.  Just change those to regular double quotes `IF(ISBLANK(_afiber_iptv), "No Data", CONVERT(_afiber_iptv,STRING))`